Caches created and never deleted
My hoster reported that I exceeded the INODES, a number that corresponds to the number of files I use.
The problem is, I discovered that the W3 Cache plugin and Hummingbird Cache conflicted and created several cache folders, taking up my entire server.
The only solution they provided me would be to delete the caches in the directories below.
wp-content/cache/object/post-queries
wp-content/cache/object/term-queries
wp-content/cache/object/comment-queries
Is there any way to resolve this issue? I can delete these folders????
I tried with Hosting support, but they only gave me FTP. I tried to start deleting these folders, but Filezilla is taking a long time to delete and the hosting said it could be deleted, but they told me that it might cause an error and I was worried.

Just delete them - don't delete the folders one by one - delete the main cache directory. You should also update the settings in your plugins to not keep cache files for an extended period of time: https://wpmudev.com/docs/wpmu-dev-plugins/hummingbird/ and https://www.boldgrid.com/support/w3-total-cache/purge-cache-log/?utm_source=W3TCFooter. Also, pick one. You don't need both.

Many cache plugins delete their files and other assets when you deactivate them. Try that. If it works, reactivate one of those two plugins and delete the other. They probably work at cross-purposes to each other.
Plugins are supposed to delete their files when you delete them from your system. Try that. You can always reinstall one of them.
If your cache files are still there you need to keep deleting them by hand.
And you should open support topics on those plugins telling the developers they need to delete files on deactivation and / or deletion.
The file manager in cpanel uses an efficient method to delete an entire folder full of files. (FileZilla enumerates the files and deletes them one by one, which is slow.)

I also had to find out the hard way that W3 Total Cache's object cache (with the option to save to the Disk) over time caused my hosting plan's inode limit to exceed, resulting in 503 errors all over the place.
Simply clearing the cache didn't help. I had to jump in and manually to delete the folder /wp-content/cache. This folder can safely be deleted as the plugin will recreate it and start over.

WordPress plugins “W3 Total Cache” and “WP-Optimize” can conflict each other.
Also, WordPress “W3 Total Cache” and “LiteSpeed Cache” can conflict.
Or like…
My advice is: check WordPress plugins, which perform caching or minification.
